# Elasticsearch Mapping Custom Propery with Script

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "exam": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "score": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "custom_score": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

i have tihs mapping. The custom_score is calculcated with this script

```
if(score >= 0)
    custom_score = score
else
    custom_score = score-100
```

Is it possible elasticsearch auto index this field? I want to use this value to make some sortings to some queries. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-transform.html) but be careful that this feature is deprecated in 2.x and will be removed in ES 5. The only options remaining for ES 5 is to do the transformation in your own client code and index the value already changed accordingly.

But, for now, using transforms:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "exam": {
      "transform": {
        "script": "if (ctx._source['score'].toInteger()>=0) ctx._source['custom_score'] = ctx._source['score'].toInteger(); else ctx._source['custom_score'] = ctx._source['score'].toInteger()-100"
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "score": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "custom_score": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```